# Find element of Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, finite-groups, abelian-groups, permutation-cycles

Let$ (1 3 5 7 )$ and $(2 3 6 8)$ be elements of $S_8$. Find a element$π$  form  $S_8$ for which it is worth 
 $π (1 3 5 7 ) π^{-1} = (2 3 6 8)$

Comment: Your existing three posts are all problem-statement questions. What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: @Saad multiplication by a on the right side, which unfortunately does not provide the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that if 
$π\in S_n$ and $(a_1, a_2,...,a_n)\in S_n $
Then $$ π(a_1, a_2,...,a_n)π^{-1}=(π(a_1),π(a_2),...,π(a_n))$$

Now from your question we get $π(1)=2,π(3)=3,π(5)=6,π(7)=8$ 
Image of $π$ for other elements we can choose at many  ,like$π(2)=5,π(4)=1,π(6)=7,π(8)=4$
 Then we get $ π=(1,2,5,6,7,8,4)$,

You can choose those four images (but for that choosing $π$ must be a bijective mapping) another way and get another$π$

Comment: Where did you get 4 from?

Comment: Which "4" are you talking about mate?

Comment: π=(1,2,5,6,7,8,4); the last element here

Comment: Now I have given the complete solution of your problem.Check the answer mate

Comment: ohh I see it now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

For instance, $(12)(56)(78)$.  There are others.